# HTML5 Video Track tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have embedded a video in HTML5 webpage using the `<Video>` tag. and also i have added the `<track>` tag for subtitles.

The video is working perfectly fine in almost all major browsers, but the **Subtitles** are not working. I know that major browsers doesn't support this.

Is there is any workaround which can show the subtitles in all browsers. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2):

[Captionator](https://github.com/cgiffard/Captionator) is a polyfill for the `<track>` tag.

Comment: Can we use this for commercial purpose?

Comment: See the license tag on the github page

Answer (score 0):

Try flow player It will be help to show subtitle and support to all major browser with video tag supported extension.

http://flowplayer.org/docs/subtitles.html

https://github.com/flowplayer/flowplayer

You can edit flow player design by below link configuration

http://flowplayer.org/designer/

Look on captionatorjs

http://captionatorjs.com/demo.html

Comment: Is this player can be used for Commercial purpose?

Comment: you can use free version but its showing flowplayer icon on left bottom side. If you want to add your business logo than you need to purchase its pro version. other wise you can use this plugin.